# How do I set a dbus property to a negative value with busctl?

Tags: linux, systemd, dbus

I'm trying to use `busctl` to set a property of type `double` to a negative value. Positive values are fine:

```
busctl set-property com.acme.foo /com/acme/foo com.acme.foo.Interface inflation d 1.0
```

but trying to change this to a negative value gives the following error:

```
busctl set-property com.acme.foo /com/acme/foo com.acme.foo.Interface inflation d -1.0
busctl: invalid option -- '1'
```

I've tried the obvious things like putting `-1.0` in single, double quotes or using a backslash to escape the `-`. There is a `--` option but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`busctl -- set-property com.acme.foo /com/acme/foo com.acme.foo.Interface inflation d -1.0`

The -- option tells busctl that everything after the -- is not an option. Like many unix tools, busctl uses optarg for it's command line parsing. See `man optarg` for more info on this.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you!